# 'OutOfMemoryException' reading 20mb XLSX file

Tags: c#, excel, out-of-memory, apache-poi, npoi

I'm using [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/) to deal with Excel files. Here's how I'm reading files:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(excelFilePath))
{
    IWorkbook wb = WorkbookFactory.Create(stream);
    ...
}
```

However, for any XLSX file larger than a few megabytes, it causes memory usage to shot up to about 1GB and eventually throw an OOM exception.

Doing some research, I've [found out](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) that, strangely, loading a workbook from a File rather than a Stream results in less memory consumption by POI. The closest C# equivalent to the provided Java examples I've come up with to use Files is the following:

```
OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.Open(new FileInfo(excelFilePath));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(pkg);
```

But it seems to use the same underlying implementation since the memory usage is still the same and causes OutOfMemory exceptions.

Does NPOI have anything built-in for handling large XLSX files?

Suggestions on alternative libraries that can handle both XLS and XLSX files are also welcome.

Comment: It's more work, but not toooo much more, to read it with SAX using the various helpers. Did you try [that approach, as documented in the POI website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems XLSX support is rather new in NPOI and it simply can't handle large files yet.

After trying a few libraries, [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) was able to process the large XLSX file without a hitch, so I finally settled on having two libraries for reading in Excel files, NPOI for XLS and EPPlus for XLSX.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion for alternative libraries, a good one is [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). I've used it extensively for both XLSX and XLS files and it does the job well. Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/madan712/3912272) to do a quick test on your file.

The only format Apache POI doesn't cover is the old format XML files for which [Xelem](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xelem/) can be used instead.