# Reading large XLSX files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, web-services

I have an application that have to read excel and convert it to array. So far so good. Everything works file until I try to convert a larger file. I try OpenXML and try SAX approach:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument xlsx = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
{
   WorkbookPart workbookPart = xlsx.WorkbookPart;
   List<List<string>> parsedContent = new List<List<string>>();
   foreach (WorksheetPart worksheet in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
       {
           OpenXmlReader xlsxReader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheet);

           while (xlsxReader.Read())
           {
           }
        }
 }
```

This is working well for files in range 1 - 10MB. My problem is when I try to load 10+ MB file. The result is OutOfMemoryException. How to proper read that big chunk of data? How to do it memory efficient?

P.s. I try libraries like ClosedXML, EPPlus and few others.

Every solution will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a big Excel document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338199/read-a-big-excel-document)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670705/outofmemoryexception-reading-20mb-xlsx-file

Comment: @VDWWD not a good duplicate - almost all of the answers are bad

Comment: @Vasil *why* do you use a List of 10M elements? That's what's causing the problem, not Excel. There's no point in using a reader when you end up keeping everything in memory. The reader makes sense only if you process the data immediately.

Comment: How are you processing the rows and why do you store them in a `List<List>` ? Shouldn't you be using an array perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I copy it bad. I am not using it that way. I just test some cases before I copy/paste the code. The case is that I will receive Base64Encoded string (the excel file) then I have to read all the date and return it as two dimensional array. What should I do in this particular case?

Comment: 10M items are 10M items, whether you allocate them at the start, or little by little. In fact, "little-by-little" is worse, because the list grows by doubling. What are you going to do with this array? Why cant' you process the data in the loop?

Comment: The requirement is that this endpoint should return the cell values in two-dimensional array, including the empty cells, compute formulas & etc. In addition what is going to be the RAM consumption of the server if 10 request for that kind of parsing are shoot against this endpoint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you plan on only performing a read on the excel file content, I suggest you use the **ExcelDataReader** library instead [Link](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/).

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        do
        {
            // Read row
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Read column values
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {               
                    var cellValue = reader.GetValue(i);
                }
            }
        }
        while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

Comment: It works just like magic. this should be accepted as the answer

Comment: Avoid calling `AsDataSet` it can take lot of memory for big files. Instead process rows in streaming manner / batches

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader). It is easy to install through Nuget and should only require a few lines of code:

Nuget:

```
Install-Package ExcelDataReader
```

Usage:

```
 using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
        {
            DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
            foreach (DataRow dr in result[0])
            {
                //Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A code sample would go a long way to improving the quality of this answer